# how to implement comment section or load more function

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a comment section that have load more comment function or looks like the image below, i can make it but it will be a huge mess code or even not working.

please let me know if you have clean approach to achieve this or you can share what package or what function to make load more comment

this is what i want to achieve

[image]

Comment: Hey, did you find out how to do this?

Comment: no, i don't. Do you want to achieve this ?